# Setting up Apache httpd with LDAP authentication for Windows WebDAV clients

Tags: windows, apache, authentication, ldap, webdav

I'm setting up an Apache HTTPD web server on a clone of RedHat Linux 6.5, using the mod_webdav module and mod_authnz_ldap.  The clients will be Windows 7 systems using Explorer with WebDAV.  The issue is that natively, mod_authnz_ldap requires basic authentication as passwords hashed with digest authentication can't be decoded properly for LDAP to use them.  And, Windows Explorer for Windows 7 and later require digest authentication for WebDAV connections.

From my research, it appears that this might be doable using SSL, but I couldn't find clear documentation on how to use SSL with WebDAV and LDAP.

Can anyone point me to instructions on how to make this work, or suggest an alternative way of reaching the goal of having Windows users using WebDAV to access files on a linux server while being authenticated / authorized by LDAP calls?

Thanks!

-steve j

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.